# How do I add the job status (success or failure) in the email notification?

Tags: octopus-deploy

I want to add the job status in the subject line of the email notification of Octopus Deploy. Can you please tell me the system variable to use or another way to add the status?

Answer (score 2):

As a work-around you could use two steps for sending the 'status-email':

1. One step sending 'success'-email. This step should have its 'Run condition' set to 'Success: only run when previous steps are successfull'.
2. Another step sending 'failure'-email. This step should have 'Run condition' set to 'Failure: only run when a previous step failed'.

Perhaps the system-variables Octopus.Deployment.Error
Octopus.Deployment.ErrorDetail could also be helpfull.[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **Tracking deployment status**
>
> During deployment, Octopus provides variables describing the status of each step.
>
> Where S is the step name, Octopus will set:
>
> - Octopus.Step[S].Status.Code
> - Octopus.Step[S].Status.Error
> - Octopus.Step[S].Status.ErrorDetail
>
> Status codes include Pending, Skipped, Abandoned, Cancelled, Running, Succeeded and Failed.

Source: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables#Systemvariables-DeploymentStatusTrackingdeploymentstatus

So to apply this to your email subject (assuming you're using the inbuilt Send Email step:

[image: Send Email Step]

FYI: the box circled allows you quick access to the variables list.

You probably want to tweak the value to be closer to this, though

```
Deployment Status = #{Octopus.Step[Other Step Name].Status.Code}
```

---

As an extension to this answer; you can iterate over **all** steps and output their status, I guess.

Syntax here: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Variable+Substitution+Syntax#VariableSubstitutionSyntax-Repetition (look for the Repetition heading)

```
Write-Host "Deployment Steps:"
#{each step in Octopus.Step}
    Write-Host "- StepName=#{step}; Status=#{step.Status.Code};"
#{/each}
```

Example output

> Deployment Steps:
>
> - StepName=FirstStep; Status=Succeeded;
> - StepName=ThisStep; Status=Running;
> - StepName=YetToBeRun; Status=Pending;

Comment: The above syntax will only send the status of individual step.  In my scenario my job has 10 steps and when i add those 10 steps status code in the email subject line, subject line would be really confusing.    Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you want the **_overall_** job status; then during the email send phase the status will be "running", which I suspect isn't as useful as you might want! Can you not simply add the status of the step prior to the email sending? If not, perhaps you need to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @Mohammed I have updated my answer to include the iterative option... but not sure that this will give you what you want, but it might help you along the way

Answer (score 0):

You could use variable expressions and deployment error variable to achieve this in email subject field. For example:

```
State of deployment: #{unless Octopus.Deployment.Error}Success#{/unless} #{if Octopus.Deployment.Error}Failure#{/if}
```